# Problem with Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Ok, so this one seems quite strange to me ... I am plotting two functions into a Manipulate Environment, both have one real variable and one real parameter (which is manipulated with the slider) ... However, one of the functions shows ***ONLY*** when I move the slider, as soon as I leave the slider at a fixed position, it disappears ... it's the blue function "L" ... any help or suggestions?

```
p[s_, r_] := Min[s, r - s]/r;
H[y_] := -y*Log[2, y] - (1 - y)*Log[2, 1 - y];
L[s_, r_] := Sqrt[2^s*2^(H[p[s, r]]*r)];
R[r_] := 3^(3/8*r);
f[x_] := 4.9 x^(1/4);
g[x_] := 4514.7 x^(1/8);
h[x_] := x^(0.96/(Log[Log[x]]));
K[x_] := Min[f[x], g[x], h[x]];
Manipulate[Plot[{Log[L[s, r]], Log[K[3^r - 1]*R[r]]}, {s, 1, 30000},PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> {"L", "RK"}], {r, 1, 30000}]
```

Comment: My version of MMA is 13.2. The blue curve only disappears for small r, when Log[L[s, r]] becomes complex.

Comment: @DanielHuber oh, interesting... I still use MMA 11, might it be an issue with that?

Still, I mean for large values the curve shouldn't disappear... what could cause this?

Comment: You may want to check that the parameters are within the function domain `FunctionDomain[Log[K[3^r - 1]*R[r]], r]`. Otherwise, I can't reproduce the problem either on *13.3.0 for Linux x86*.